# Dynamic route in express not invoking callback from $http GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have a factory in angular which has the following get request

```
  dataFactory.checkDb = function(artist){
     return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/artist/' + artist
    })
  };
```

The second half of the url is variable. So for that reason I wrote an express handler for get requests like so:

```
app.get('/artist/*',dbhelpers.checkDbArtist)
```

For some reason `dbhelpers.checkDbArtist` doesn't get invoked and I get the following error in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/artist/Drake 404 (Not Found)
```

Drake is the variable artist name in this case.

I previously had the follow code which works well:

**factory.js**

```
  dataFactory.checkDb = function(artist){
     return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/artistsearch',
        params: {artistname: artist}
    })
  };
```

**express.js**

```
app.get('/artistsearch',dbhelpers.checkDbArtist)


app.post('/artistsearch', dbhelpers.insertDb)
```

This doesn't work when I type www.localhost.com/#/artist/Drake, because I get an empty view without data, because `dbhelpers.checkDbArtist` isn't being invoked. What I want to do is for my app to hit www.localhost.com/#/artist/Drake and make the appropiate get request. I want to pass my data in the url and not in `params: {artistname: artist}` Any ideas?

Comment: You're sure you don't want something like `app.get('/artist/:artist'` and then use `params.artist` to capture it ?

Comment: You should probably show your other routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
app.get('/artist/*',dbhelpers.checkDbArtist)
```

to

```
app.get('/artist/:artist',dbhelpers.checkDbArtist)
```

And inside your dbhelpers.checkDbArtist you can get the param like this

```
req.params.artist
```